# Windows Mobile Appliacation works in Professional 6.5 Emulator but not in WM 6.5 Device

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.5

I am developing a mobile application for WM 6.5. I have a Form with 2 comboboxes and I am binding with database.

This working fine in Emulator 6.5 but not in WM 6.5 Device.

I also installed CAB files

sqlce.ppc.wce5.armv4i

sqlce.repl.ppc.wce5.armv4i

NETCFv35.Messages.EN

NETCFv35.wm.armv4i

in device.

I am not getting any idea about this if any one known about this issue please suggest me.

Thanks,

Balu.

Comment: We are not getting any idea about what is not working :)

Comment: and BTW accept some nswers for your previous questions.

Comment: What does "Not Working" mean?

Comment: Sorry for delay....i am not able to see Combo box list values in Device.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the application while connected via ActiveSync so you can step through the code?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have something installed on your emulator that is not installed on the device.